# Mysql query search one column and replace another

Tags: mysql, select, replace

I've got a large database table and wanting to select rows in the column 'cat_id' containing the value "79", then replace all the values in a column called "system" with the value "6" for the selected rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do that:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `system` = '6' WHERE `cat_id` = '79'
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be misunderstanding you, but i think you are looking for a simple update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET system = 6
WHERE cat_id = 79;
```